# Typescript Record without manually typing keys

Tags: typescript, react-native

I need some help with Typescript Records.

I'm looking for a solution that avoids manually typing keys names as a key type for a Record, but still keeping intelisense for that object.

[Intelisense example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcRyT.png)

For example:

```
import { StyleProp, TextStyle } from 'react-native';

//I would like to avoid manually typing dozens of keys here. 
//Can it somehow automatically fetch keys that are already inside the fonts object?
type TFontKeys =
  | 'title'
  | 'subtitle'
  | 'header'
///////

const fonts: Record<TFontKeys, StyleProp<TextStyle>> = {
  title: {
    fontSize: 22,
    fontWeight: '600',
  },
  subtitle: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: '600',
  },
  header: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: '500',
    marginBottom: 8,
  }}
```

I know that I can simply use

```
Record<string, StyleProp<TextStyle>>
```

But then I lose intelisense for fonts.properties

[Without intelisense](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfBMC.png)

If a Record is not made for this, is there anything else that can do this?

Thank you~

Comment: More information is needed.  "Can it somehow automatically fetch keys that are already inside the fonts object?" Is there a static definition of the fonts object anywhere or is it dynamic? If it's dynamic, there is no source for Typescript to do the type generation. If it's statically defined, it may be doable.

Comment: Static in this case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object type can't refer itself so you can create a new one using the other types, something like this:

```js
    import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
    
    const fonts = {
      title: {
        fontSize: 22,
        fontWeight: '600',
      },
      subtitle: {
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: '600',
      },
      header: {
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: '500',
        marginBottom: 8,
      },
    }
    
    export const typedFonts = StyleSheet.create<
      Record<keyof typeof fonts, any>
    >(fonts)
```

And then use the `typedFonts` as your style:

[image]

Success on your project

Comment: The part with typedFonts works great! I can see all the keys with intelisense when using prepared typedFonts, however I then loose intelisense with fonts object when defining styles. If I cast StyleProp<TextStyle>> on fonts, it works, but then your solution does not work with typedFonts

Comment: Hmmm, so to add the autocomplete for the text properties you may use something like this on the end of each  property: `title: {... ...} as TextStyle,`
Not the cleanest solution but will give you the available text properties to use.

Comment: This works too, but as you said it is not a clean solution. If no one finds a better solution soon, I will accept the first answer as it answered my original question.